# Using Variable in sqlite

Tags: android, iphone, sqlite, mobile

I am making a quiz app in which i have to select the number of question depending upon user choice.Actually i want to something like this

```
    db.execute('select * from Quiz limit **Variable**')//Here i want to use variable instead of constant value.
```

Could you help me in this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Learn about the [`query` method and placeholders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as:

```
public void selectall(String variable){

Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT from Quiz limit "+variable);

}
```

where variable is set according to user selection

**NOTE :** `db.execute` is not [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) class method in Android you will need to use [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) or [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods for quering database table

and see this tutorial for performing all select,delete,update and insert operation on database in android :

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: You're recommending that a (probable) newbie uses string concatenation for SQL? Really? That's a little irresponsible don't you think?

Comment: @muistooshort : but this is a way in Android  SQLiteDatabase for preparing database query .rawQuery method take an string as param

Comment: But there are methods that can use placeholders.

Comment: @muistooshort : yes we have  SQLiteDatabase.query method which already i have mention in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this:

```
 int num = 10;
 db.execSQL("select * from Quiz limit "  + num)
```